# nodejs app is not able to connect to REST api nodejs app

Tags: node.js, windows-10

I have a nodejs REST api hosted on localhost and I have a nodejs app that is consuming it. This app too is running on localhost. Everything was working fine but after a restart the webapp just could not connect to the REST api anymore. I am running Windows 10.

I tested the REST api with postman and also with browser, it worked. There is no issue with the REST api.

Tried changing the port numbers - same result.

I ran wireshark to see the difference between when requesting from browser and from nodejs webapp. Below is the screenshot. First two lines are when the nodejs app made the request and the next two are from browser.
[image: Wireshark capture]

I am not able to understand what is wrong here. I tried with a standalone nodejs script, that too failed. Below is the script I used.

```
var request = require('request');
var u = "xxx";
var p = "xxx";
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(u + ":" + p).toString("base64");
var username = "qqqq";
var password = "eeee";



var options = {

            url : 'http://localhost:4001/api/v1/transaction',
            headers : {
                "Authorization" : auth
            },
        };   

        console.log(options.url);

        request.get(options, function(error,response,body){
            //console.log(options);
            //console.log(response);
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            console.log(body);
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var userObj = JSON.parse(body);
                callback(userObj);
            } else {
                console.log("---- Error ----")
                console.log(error);             
            }
        });
```

Comment: Check the headers, I assume the application is looking for specific headers, like Host, and User-Agent, etc..

Comment: Then why did it work before the restart?

Comment: @unlimit who knows. All we can do is look at the symptoms and make educated guesses. From the looks of it, it is reaching the server, but the server doesn't appear to have a resource at the requested path.

Comment: Why the downvote? At least tell me the reason for it.

Comment: @unlimit the question is unclear. not useful.

Comment: @KevinB, does the question make sense now?

Comment: well, no. not unless you show evidence of being unable to connect. The image you've included seems to show otherwise.

Comment: @KevinB, the resource exists. The same url was tested with browser. It responded with data.

Comment: You received a 404 error, not an unable to connect error. The server is giving you a 404 error. Why would the server give you a 404 error? We have no information related to said server, so all we can do is tell you what the error message is telling you.

Comment: @KevinB, yes 404 means not able to connect. But why? Why does it work with postman, browser but not from nodejs script? Any ideas?

Comment: Something about request A is different from request B. Just looking at your image, the content length is clearly different for both requests. What else is different? Is the server incorrectly responding with 404 when it should be responding with 401? who knows, we can't see said server's error handling authentication or routing.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and I am posting the answer in the hope that someone would find it useful.

My hint was from the wireshark. (screenshot in the question) All successful requests went to `[::1]` not `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. After the reboot of the windows 10 machine, the REST api nodejs app was actually no longer serving on the `ip v4 localhost` but was serving on `ip v6 localhost`. There was absolutely no issue with the code.

Instead of using `localhost` in the url in the consuming webapp, I changed it to `[::1]` and it started to work.

```
.....
.....    

var options = {

        //url : 'http://localhost:4001/api/v1/transaction',
        // replaced localhost with [::1]
        url : 'http://[::1]:4001/api/v1/transaction',
        headers : {
            "Authorization" : auth
        },
    };   

.....
.....
```